# Anti-Toxicity Filter Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have an anti toxicity filter in my discord bot, but I wanna make it so that users can manually set it up using a command and if it isn't set up then it won't do anything when users are being toxic! I'd like to use json to make this work, any help would be appreciated!

```py
cuss_words = []

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 for word in cuss_words :
    if word in message.content:
      await message.delete()
      await message.channel.send("Please don't be toxic!", delete_after=10)
  await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to read from a json file, use:

```py
with open("your_json_file.json", "r") as json_file:
    json_dict = json.load(json_file) #this gets the contents of the json file and loads them to a dict object.
```

and to write to a json file, use:

```py
with open("your_json_file.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(json_dict, json_file) #here you change to contents of json_file to json_dict
```

Now to enable users being able to set their own words up, I suggest an `add_toxic_word` command, which would add that word to the list of words for that guild:

```py
# in your setup command, "word" is a variable which contains the word to block
with open("your_json_file.json", "r") as json_file:
    toxic_words = json.load(json_file)
try:
    old_guild_toxic_words = toxic_words[ctx.guild.id]
    new_guild_toxic_words = old_guild_toxic_words.append(word)
    toxic_words[guild.id] = new_guild_toxic_words
except KeyError:
    toxic_words[guild.id] = word
with open("your_json_file.json", "w") as json_file:
    json.dump(toxic_words, json_file)
```

Before running the code you have to create the json file with the content `{}`.
Now in your `on_message`, you have to read the json file at the top like this:

```py
with open("your_json_file.json", "r") as json_file:
    toxic_words = json.load(json_file)
    try:
        cuss_words = toxic_words[guild.id]
    except KeyError:
        cuss_words = []
```

This allows people to set their system up, and only when they added words, it filters any.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks for the reply, I'll be right at it to try and implement it in the bot!

Answer (score -1):

You could make a global variable named something like `toxicity_active`. Add a command to set that variable to `True` and `False`. Then, simply change `if word in message.content:` to `if word in message.content and toxicity_active:` This will only delete the message if `toxicity_active` is `True`.

Comment: This isn't good as it won't work for a specific server and if it doesn't then users can literally add gibberish which can result in destroying my bot and making it more of a spam bot.